# カーネルを残したままディストリビューションだけ変えることはできますか

Tags: linux

例えばUbuntuからfedoraへ変更するようなことはできますか
パーティションや今あるデスクトップのファイルを消したくないのですがなにかよい方法はありませんか

Comment: できるできない以前に、まずなぜそのようなことがしたいのかを具体的に示したほうがよいと思います。ディストリビューションを変更することで、どういう効果が得られることを期待しているのでしょうか？

Comment: 基本的に、主流のディストリビューションのインストール方法で,既設のパーティションを使うオプションが出てくる可能性があると思います。主流のパーティションタイプなら(例えばext2,ext3,ext4)大丈夫と思います。 前のカーネルを使う場合はちょっと微妙ですけど：ディストリビューションによっては、多様のカーネルモジュールや設定ファルの体制が違うかもしれませんし、新しいディストリビューションをインストールすると、前のファイルが書き換えられます。

Comment: 現在のディスクの構成（ディスクの本数、パーティションのレイアウト、RAIDや論理ボリュームの有無など）を書いてくださいますか。

Comment: @take88 より具体的にかければ、とてもよい回答をいただけると思ったのですが、よく考えたら仮想化で十分でした。また機会がありましたら、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どうしてそうしたいのかよくわからないのですが、今Ubuntuを使っていて、Fedoraもちょっと見てみたい、けどUbuntuを消してインストールし直すのは嫌だ。というなら、Dockerとか試してみるのはいかがでしょうか。